# How to retrieve SAFARI Object through Xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

How to retrieve Safari, or my default browser's instance object, if I open the URL using following code for iPad

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];
```

Comment: You can't take safari object in your application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, once you open the URL safari moves to the foreground, replacing your app. From the documentation:

> If the resource is another application, invoking this method may cause
>   the calling application to quit so the other one can be launched.

But you can create your own view controller inside your app with a web view and implement some basic browser controls if you like. The `UIWebView` class has `goBack` and `goForward` methods you can use for that.